Slicing with Arrays
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(28).reshape(4, 7)
print(X)
print(X[::2,::3])

Can someone please explain what the print statement does?

Looks like you are slicing a 2D array with a step of 2 for the rows, and 3 for the columns.

OutPut : [
          [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
          [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
          [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
          [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
         ]
          [[ 0  3  6]
          [14 17 20]
         ]

Explanation :
 1.  X = np.arange(28).reshape(4, 7)


np.arange(28) generates an array of integers from 0 to 27

.reshape(4, 7) reshapes this 1D array into a 2D array with 4 rows and 7
columns.


This results in the following array X:
      [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
      [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
      [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
      [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]]


Slicing the Array X
 X[::2, ::3]




X[::2, ::3] uses slicing to extract specific rows and columns from X.

::2 in the row position means "select every second row," which corresponds to rows with indices 0 and 2.

::3 in the column position means "select every third column," which corresponds to columns with indices 0, 3, and 6.


Applying these slices to X:

Rows selected:

Row 0: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
Row 2: [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]


Columns selected within these rows:

Column 0, Column 3, Column 6 for both rows.
So the Result  is
[[ 0  3  6]
[14 17 20]]





So, the output is a subset of the original array X, selecting every second row and every third column.

THank you very much for your help. It helps me a lot.
